# how to write multiple variables to a single LCD display line?

Tags: python, sensors, lcd

I'm a noob in Python, so please bear with me.
The following code is for humidity and temperature sensors reading to an LCD screen 20x4 connected through I2C interface.
the program works fairly well! but I would like to include the reading in celsius as well as fahrenheit in the same line, how can I display the value 'f' or 'f1' (representing Fahrenheit conversion) right after the Celsius measurement so it does look like :

Temp_Entry:20.4C/68F
........

Thank you!!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import lcddriver 
import time
import Adafruit_DHT as dht

lcd = lcddriver.lcd()

while (True):

#Read values from AM2302 Sensors in Pin 4 & 24
    h,t = dht.read_retry(dht.AM2302, 4)
    h1,t1 = dht.read_retry(dht.AM2302, 24)
#Humidity calibration compensation
    h1 += 5
    h -= 9 
#Celcius to Fahrenheit conversion
    f = t * 9 / 5 + 32
    f1 = t1 * 9 / 5 + 32
# Print temp and humidity values
    lcd.cursor_pos = (0,0)
    lcd.lcd_display_string ('Temp_Entry:{0:0.1f}C'.format(t1), 1)
    lcd.lcd_display_string ('Hum_Entry :{1:0.1f}%'.format(t1, h1), 2)
    lcd.lcd_display_string ('Temp_Back :{0:0.1f}C'.format(t), 3)
    lcd.lcd_display_string ('Hum_Back  :{1:0.1f}%'.format(t, h), 4)

    time.sleep(10)
```

Final code (after correction/cleanup) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import lcddriver
import time
import Adafruit_DHT as dht

lcd = lcddriver.lcd()

while (True):

#Read values from AM2302 Sensors in Pin 4 & 24
    h,t = dht.read_retry(dht.AM2302, 4)
    h1,t1 = dht.read_retry(dht.AM2302, 24)
#Humidity calibration compensation
    h1 += 5
    h -= 9 
#Celcius to Fahrenheit conversion
    f = t * 9 / 5 + 32
    f1 = t1 * 9 / 5 + 32
# Print temp and humidity values
    lcd.cursor_pos = (0,0)
    lcd.lcd_display_string ('Temp_Ent:{0:0.1f}C/{1:0.1f}F'.format(t1, f1), 1)
    lcd.lcd_display_string ('Hum_Ent :{0:0.1f}%'.format(h1), 2)
    lcd.lcd_display_string ('Temp_Bak:{0:0.1f}C/{1:0.1f}F'.format(t, f), 3)
    lcd.lcd_display_string ('Hum_Bak :{0:0.1f}%'.format(h), 4)

    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue the string like this:

```
'Temp_Back :{0:0.1f}C/{1:0.1f}F'.format(t, f)
```

and in fact I do not get why you gave every line in the .format two parameters when you everytime call only one.
This is how it works:

```
"{0} {1}".format("Hello", "World")
```

will result:

> Hello World

The parameter in the bracers will just call the paramter in the __th place, that's why (t,f) will let you call both the temprature in celcius and farenheit in the same line.